# Spotify SDK for iOS, How to clear playerQueue

Tags: ios, spotify, spotify-app, spotify-queue

I'm new to the Spotify SDK.

I just implemented `auth`, `login` and getting some track URIs. That works.
However I can't find reset or clear music queue that is currently playing.

I think `[SPTAudioStreamingController queueURIs: clearQueue: callback:];` is what I need.

However on my environment with SDK beta6 and iOS8, it just adds tracks to the end of the queue and never clears the current queue.

```
//Reset current queue and replace it with new URIs?
[self.player queueURIs:uris clearQueue:YES callback:nil];
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use another function, which replaces all playing tracks with the given.

```
[self.player replaceURIs:tracks withCurrentTrack:0 callback:^(NSError *error) {
     if(error){
        NSLog(@"*** Error occurred while trying replace playing track %@", error);
       return;
     }
 }];
```